# Nodemon with IcedCoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, iced-coffeescript, nodemon

First of all, I install nodemon globally:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Then I try to start my apllication using the following command:

```
nodemon app.iced
```

And I get such error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". However, I can run my application without nodemon without any errors:

```
iced --nodejs --debug app.iced
```

What the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting your app with:

`nodemon -x iced app.iced`

Also, if you're using `nodemon` you're probably interested in monitoring and restarting on changes to your codebase. So, if you want to automatically restart when an `.iced` file changes, you could do:

`nodemon -x iced app.iced -e ".iced"`

For more useful information on `nodemon` parameters, use `nodemon --help`.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't need the `-e ".iced" as nodemon looks at the script you used to run and automatically looks at that extension (I'm the author of nodemon).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Remy! You're right, in this case you don't need `-e "iced"`... Most likely, you're only going to need it if you're monitoring multiple file types (.iced, .js, etc.)...

Comment: Hey @RemySharp. Why don't you bring IcedCoffeeScript support?